# Custom function in Google sheet app script stops executing after returning a value 1 time. It has to return value multiple times until loop breaks

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

```
function sizeCable(vD, svD, dCur) {  
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LVPC");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CableData");
  var cableSizes = sheet2.getRange("CableData!U4:U19").getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cableSizes.length; i++) {
    var sizeSel = cableSizes[i][0];
    var voltageDrop = sheet1.getRange(vD).getValue();
    var sVoltageDrop = sheet1.getRange(svD).getValue();
    var deratedCurrent = sheet1.getRange(dCur).getValue();
    
    if (voltageDrop == "SUCCEED" && sVoltageDrop == "SUCCEED" && deratedCurrent == "SUCCEED") {
      break;}
    else {
     console.log(sizeSel);return sizeSel}
  }
}
```

the above function stops executing after the first else result (CableData!U4 value). It was supposed to execute multiple times.

```
function sizeCable(vD, svD, dCur) {  
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LVPC");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CableData");
  var cableSizes = sheet2.getRange("CableData!U4:U19").getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cableSizes.length; i++) {
    var sizeSel = cableSizes[i][0];
    var voltageDrop = sheet1.getRange(vD).getValue();
    var sVoltageDrop = sheet1.getRange(svD).getValue();
    var deratedCurrent = sheet1.getRange(dCur).getValue();
    
    if (voltageDrop == "SUCCEED" && sVoltageDrop == "SUCCEED" && deratedCurrent == "SUCCEED") {
      break;}
    else {
     console.log(sizeSel)}
  }
}
```

when I try with only log, I can see following result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLCGK.png)